# Create a virtual host Cent OS

Tags: linux, apache, centos

How to create a virtual host in cent os?

I have change some in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf file

```
<VirtualHost local.mydomain.com>
ServerAdmin webmaster@mydomain.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/test/
ServerName local.mydomain.com
ServerAlias local.mydomain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

and in /etc/hosts file

```
127.0.0.1       dexs01 localhost.localdomain6 localhost #existing lines
::1             localhost6.localdomain6 localhost #existing lines
127.0.0.1       local.mydomain.com       local.mydomain.com #my addition
```

and then I restarted my Apache server
so what wrong in this?

Comment: the best thing to do in this case is to check the apache logs, in most cases it will tell exactly what the problem is if it's something in the  httpd.conf file

Comment: Also, it's good to maybe mention what actually happens when you hit your domain in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

you have to define in the [VirtualHost](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#virtualhost) directive the IP and the port:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ...
  ServerName local.mydomain.com
  ...
</VirtualHost>
```

the rest looks good.
note: in your case you do not need the [ServerAlias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#serveralias) directive because it matches your ServerName.